# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n}f =0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^1(E)$ and $(E_n)$ be a sequence of measurable subsets of $E$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} m(E_n)=0$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n}f =0$.

I know this can be done using an $\varepsilon - \delta$ lemma, but Im looking for an answer using convergence theorems or something. If you've got something, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempting to apply the dominated convergence theorem, but the sequence $\left(f\mathbf 1_{E_n}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ may not converge to $0$ almost everywhere. For example, if $2^N\leqslant n\lt 2^{N+1}$, define $E_n=\left[\left(n-2^N\right)  2^{-N},\left(n+1-2^N\right)  2^{-N}   \right)  $. Its Lebesgue measure is $2^{-n}$ but $\left| f\right| \sup_{2^N\leqslant n\lt 2^{N+1}} \mathbf 1_{E_n}=\left| f\right|$.

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}m\left(E_n\right)$ was convergent, then we would have the almost sure convergence to $0$. This issue can be solved using subsequences.

Suppose that $\left(\int_{E_n}   f\mathbf 1_{E_n}\mathrm dm\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ does not converge to $0$: there exists a positive $\delta$ and an increasing sequence of positive integers $\left(n_j\right)_{j=1}^{+\infty}$ such that for each $j\geqslant 1$, $\left|\int_{E_{n_j}} f\mathrm dm\right|\gt\delta$. Now, there exists an increasing sequence of integers $\left(l_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ such that for each $i$,   $m\left(E_{l_i}\right)\leqslant i^{-2}$ and $\left\{l_i,i\geqslant 1\right\}\subset \left\{n_j,j\geqslant 1\right\}$. Indeed, define $l_1$ such that $l_1=n_{j_0}$ for some $j_0$ and $m\left(E_{n_{j_0}}\right)\lt 1$ and
$$l_{i+1} :=\inf\left\{n_j\mid n_j\gt l_i\mbox{ and }m\left(E_{l_{ i+1} }\right)\leqslant \left(i+1\right)^{-2}    \right\}.$$
Let $A_i:=E_{l_i}$. Since   $\left\{l_i,i\geqslant 1\right\}\subset \left\{n_j,j\geqslant 1\right\}$, we have for each $i\geqslant 1$, 
$$\left|\int_{A_i} f\mathrm dm\right|\gt\delta\mbox{ and }m\left(A_i\right)\lt i^{-2}.$$
The sequence $\left(f\mathbf 1_{A_i }\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ converges to $0$ pointwise and the dominated convergence theorem yields a contradiction.

Comment: A solid answer, very thorough and detailed. Much appreciated. On the side, this actually might not have an answer, but how did this idea come to you?

Comment: Usually, when we are stuck, we try to convert the problem into one we can solve. When the sequence of measures is summable, we apply the dominated convergence theorem. We can thus treat _a_ subsequence, but actually _all_ subsequences.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Again, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f=I_A$ where $A$ is a measurable set. Then it is trivial that
$$0\leq\int_{E_n} f = m(A\cap E_n)\leq m(E_n)$$
so $\lim_n \int_{E_n} f =0$.
Now extend this to simple functions, and next to every $f\geq 0$ using the monotonous convergence theorem:

Let $f=\lim_n f_n$, where $f_n$ are simple functions. We know that, for each $n\in \mathbb N$, $\lim_m \int_{E_m} f_n=0$. Now, using the monotonous convergence theorem:

$$\int_{E_m} f=\int_{E_m} \lim_n f_n = \lim_n \int_{E_m} f_n$$

and now $$\lim_m \int_{E_m} f = \lim_n \lim_m \int_{E_m} f_n=0$$
Last, for $f\in L^1$, write $f=f^+-f^-$.

Comment: That's the thing, how do you alternate the limits when extending it to positive functions?